# Open the ABPeoplePicker in a UIPopover

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have a UIPopover with a button in it that opens the ABPeoplePicker. I have it opening in the popover but it shifts over. It doesn't stay in the same spot and the size changes how do I keep it the same size.

// code to call popover

```
- (IBAction) addPerson:(id) sender{
// create your view controller if it doesn't exist yet
if (addPersonViewController == nil){
    addPersonViewController = [[addPersonViewControllerPopover_iPad alloc] init];
}
pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:addPersonViewController];
// rest of your method...
addPersonViewController.delegate = self;
pop.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(790, 35, 175, 300);
[pop presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
[addPersonController retain]; 
NSLog(@"this one");
}
```

//popover code

```
- (IBAction) AddButtonAction:(id)sender {
picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
picker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor brownColor];
   picker.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 480);

picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
picker.modalInPopover = YES;
// Display only a person's phone, email, and birthdate
NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty], 
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty],
                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonBirthdayProperty], nil];

picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;

//Show the picker 
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

[picker release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this

```
picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

Comment: It works but the popover size changes and gets distorted how do I make it the old size?